# How do I change the filename for each activestorage attachment variant in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using rails 7 and have a model with an attachment called 'image':

```rb
IMAGE_VARIANTS  = {
  cover: [426, 426],
  medium: [1280, 1280],
  large: [1920, 1920],
  full: [2560, 2560]
}
    
has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
  for variant_name in IMAGE_VARIANTS.keys
    attachable.variant variant_name, resize_to_fit: IMAGE_VARIANTS[variant_name]
  end
end
```

As you can see, I've a bunch of variants.
In one of my views, I have a link to download each one of these variants. E.g.:

```
<%= link_to rails_blob_path(@post.image.variant(:cover), disposition: "attachment"), class: "hover:underline" do %>
```

I've found that each download link uses the same file name as the original uploaded file.

How can I rename the file for each variant?

Answer (score 1):

You can format your link like this

```
<%= link_to 'Cover', rails_blob_path(@post.image.variant(:cover)), download: "cover_#{@post.image.filename}" %>
```

Here [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) attribute specifies that the target (the file specified in the href attribute) will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink. The value of that attribute is will be the new name of the file after it is downloaded. You can specify necessary filename such way

NB: it's better to use `each` instead of `for` cycle

```rb
has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
  IMAGE_VARIANTS.each do |variant_name, resize_to_fit|
    attachable.variant variant_name, resize_to_fit: resize_to_fit
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it didn't work. Is this browser specific?

Comment: Currently [95.41%](https://caniuse.com/download) browsers support it. But it has another restriction: [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources) specification says in cross-origin situations, the `download` attribute has to be combined with the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header

Comment: This is what the output looks like. I also tried adding data-turbolinks: "false" just to ensure turbo isn't altering behaviour. I've also tried in a different browser... no change!

`<a class="hover:underline" download="cover.png" href="/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBY3c9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--/theCover.png">download</a>`


 
It looks like the response is 302, so I'm guessing the redirect cancels out the download attribute.